# How to instantiate an object whose constructor uses yield?

Tags: javascript, constructor, yield, co

I have a helper constructor that uses a `yield` statement:

```
var co = require('co');

var Helper = co(function* () {
    var response = yield foo();
})
module.exports.Helper = Helper;
```

I would like to instantiate it:

```
var Helper = require('./helper.js').Helper;
var helper = new yield Helper();  // TypeError
```

But I get the following error:  `TypeError: You may only yield a function, promise, generator, array, or object, but the following was passed: "[object Object]"`.

Any ideas on how to instantiate it correctly?

---

**Edit**

Removed references to koa, because I'm using co (as pointed out by vanthome).

Comment: related if not duplicate: [Is it bad practice to have a constructor function return a Promise?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24398699/1048572) (or: …use the `yield` keyword)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no point in using the `new` operator on a generator function here. operator.

Also your example has nothing to do with [koajs](http://koajs.com/), you are plainly using [co](https://github.com/tj/co) here, which is a different thing.
Sinve version 4 of co, the call `co(...)` [gives you a promise](https://github.com/tj/co#co-v4) that you can work with.

Comment: Ah, I seem to be muddling a few things here.  Thanks for response!

Comment: I don't think `new yield …` would be syntactically wrong. You just needed to have the yield expression return a constructor function :-)

Comment: Use this guide as introduction to Generators: http://davidwalsh.name/es6-generators It's the best I know.

@Bergi: you're so right, I've updated the answer.